# Why is Int63n from Go's rand package called that?

Tags: go

From the official [Go docs](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Int63n):

> Int63n returns, as an int64, a non-negative pseudo-random number in
>   [0,n) from the default Source. It panics if n <= 0.

Why is it called Int63n when it returns a 64 bit integer?

Comment: Because it has only 63 significant bits. The sign bit is ignored.

Comment: The wording on the `int63` function is probably clearer: `Int63 returns a non-negative pseudo-random 63-bit integer as an int64`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Int63n returns, as an int64, a non-negative pseudo-random number in [0,n) from the default Source

`int64` is a 64-bit **signed** integer type. That means it has 1 sign bit and 63 significant bits. That means that anything returning a **non-negative** int64 is producing 63 bits of data (the 64th bit, the sign bit, will always have the same value).